# How to search git branch for a file name once committed?

Tags: git

A while back in a known branch i committed a file, which was subsequently removed. Many iterations later, i'd like to recover this file.

How can this be done please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remember the file name, you can just run `git log -- <filename>` to show all commits that involved that file. If you don't remember the file name, but remember something about the contents, you can use `git log -S <string>` or `git log -G <regex>` to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

`git log -U | less`

find the most recent commit that referenced the filename

`git checkout MOST-RECENT-COMMIT FILENAME`